# Open a new web page and automatically enter login details and fetch data from javascript object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

In my code I can open a new browser tab using this

```
window.open("localhost.test-login.com");
```

Now on this new page I want to automatically enter username and password and click on login button. After logging in, there is a script tag in the home page which has an object. I want to fetch data from this object.

Can I achieve this without using any external tool such as selenium?

Comment: Is the new page on the same domain, or is it on a different domain?

Comment: @terrymorse different domain